# How can I find the real location of the tmp dir for a specific program on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Ubuntu creates a separate `/tmp` directory for each user, so when Apache asks for `/tmp` it actually gets `/tmp/systemd-private-654e145185f84f6ba097649873c88a9c-apache2.service-uUyzNh/tmp`. (That code is different each time.) This is generally a good thing, but it’s annoying me now.

I want to create a bunch of PDF files (using TCPDF in PHP) in `/tmp`, then use `shell_exec()` in PHP to run the `pdfunite` script to create a single output PDF, then load that PDF into memory to serve it to the browser. My problem is that the `pdfunite` script doesn’t work, which I presume is because it’s not seeing the same path as the files are actually in.

Does PHP’s `shell_exec()` run code as the Apache user (`www-data`)? If so, I would assume that it would see the same `/tmp` dir, but in that case the `pdfunite` script should work. Is there a sensible workaround here, other than using a different directory and doing the cleanup myself?

Comment: Are the "/tmp/systemd-private....." files root? Try ls -la /tmp to see. That might be why because like you say, running pdfunite via php will be running as www-data

Comment: I'm doing the messy workaround of doing it in another dir and then deleting it myself, which I'm not happy with at all, so I'll be coming back to this tomorrow.

Comment: You would have to run "sudo pdfunite" via php for it to work with those files. Doing that though would mean you would need to add a file to your /etc/sudoers.d/anyfilenamehere with something like: "www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pdfunite" allowing pdfunite to be run by www-data as sudo without a password. Something for you to think about and try maybe.. (use visudo to create your sudoers file so it checks the syntax)

Comment: On trying again, it worked fine, and I have no idea what was wrong before. Maybe I should just delete this question.